# How solve method sort() in ng-repeat AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created an array with numbers, but in the method sort() not ordering it correctly in ng-repeat.

eg

```
$scope.order = ['1', '10', '11', '22', '29', '2'];
```

eg

```
<li ng-repeat="key in order.sort()">{{key}}</li>
```

see how ordered

```
1 10 11 2 22 29
```

not

```
1 2 10 11 22 29
```

eg
http://jsfiddle.net/YWsJ7/

Comment: You have created an array of *strings* and they sort alphabetically. Delete the quotes to make it an array of numbers: `[1,10,11,...]`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos the result will be the same.

Comment: @KyleNeedham You are right, I never saw this (insane) fine print in `Array.sort()`; the comment that it is an array of strings however still holds. Sort an array of numbers by providing the simple comparator to sort: `[1, 10, 11, 22, 29, 2].sort(function(a,b){return a-b;})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `orderBy` filter with `expression` parameter. In the following example each value of the array will be passed to `parseInt` function and then values will be compared using `<`, `>` and `=`:

**JavaScript**

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {  
    $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
    $scope.order = ['1', '10', '11', '22', '29', '2'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="key in order | orderBy : parseInt ">{{key}}</li>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kRRc/3/

Documentation on [orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter

Comment: This doesn't work when the collection is not an array. For example:          $scope.numList = {"1":{name:"1"}, "2":{name:"2"}, "10":{name:"10"}, "21":{name:"21"}}; and <li ng-repeat="key in numList | orderBy:parseInt">{{key.name}}</li>

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the angular [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) method:

```
 <li ng-repeat="key in order | orderBy: 'value'">{{key.value}}</li>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YWsJ7/1/)